# Zend Framework - Module within a modules?

Tags: zend-framework, module

I have created some separate modules - beaches / villages / activities

What I would like to do is use google maps in each of these modules.

I was thinking of adding a maps module and call it into each of these modules??

What do you think...

Any ideas, tips or suggestions welcome

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing a bit more about what you are trying to achieve with Google Maps it's hard to say. But I'll take a leap and say that another Module isnt the correct way to proceed.

It seems like it could be something that a View Helper can take care of: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

If you just want to load maps based on a geographical location then some JavaScript would be the way to go.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/#AJAX_Loader

You could create your own little JS library and call it with the co-ords' you need for that module via the View.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the idea. I have droped the code into a helper.

The main functionality is for each module to call upon its table and display some results. E.g Beaches would generate a list of beaches and also insert each and its pointer onto the map !!

I shall now look at getting the dat aout of a db and then populating the new helper !!